# Can i enter italy again? US student

Tags: schengen, us-citizens, italy

I started my first year of  university in italy in october 2016-june 2017, all my affairs(permit+grades) in order,  went back to my residence, came back on the 15th of august 2015, during which issues came up and therefore i was unable to do the whole permit thing and pay uni. I was there until December 12, and i went back to Italy on the 19th of January until the 31st of May. I was attending classes, cause you can do that, but i couldn’t pay or really go back to where i am living at that moment. I came back, and only recently i found out that there is a chance i might not be let in.

This is a theory though. I might be let it.or not. HAD i known this, i would have applied for a schengen visa in june, and i wasn’t certain about going back to italy until september 10( out of my hands). I can’t ask my friend to get these documents, because i need to do it myself, in order to continue in italy ( reapply for a student visa), and no one will give it to a person with a different mail.

My guess is that i got let in back in jan and left in may with no fine or border ban( they should have told me if they did, right) is because the permit was in the renewal stage, which i couldn’t do –

So do you guys/girls think that it’s possible my regular 90/180 free travelling kicks when i step foot in italy? And yes, i have a meeting at the embassy at the end of the week to check.I just need to get into italy to fix my affairs. 
 If you know anything, it would really mean a lot if you could share the information –

I had a residence permit, that was valid for a year. In Italy you have to do it every year, unlike most eu countries

Comment: Please change the title.

Comment: What should i change it to? And can you answer my question if you can please?

Comment: You should change it to a title which describes your question if you want the people here at least read it. "URGENT SCHENGEN ISSUE ITALY" ( and in CAPS!) does not describe anything!

Comment: It’s my first question and i’m worried, i’ll chane you,sorry if it offended you

Comment: If you're worried you can always apply for a visa to be doubly sure, but you've left it a little late.

Comment: Roddy, what do you think?

Comment: I think there's always a chance it'll go one way or the other, and that your buddy should mail you the documents.

Comment: Can you please redact out all the irrelevant information about your wallet, your personal problems and your friends flat and more clearly describe what has actually happened? You are obviously describing events going over several years, but for all the relevant events, you only mention the month or date, but not in which year. Unless I miss something, you also don't tell for which periods or durations you had a visa or residence permit.

Comment: You said you had to reapply at the uni. At what time did you leave the uni, or stop being a student?

Comment: @George88 I still don’t understand the timeline for all your date(s) of entry/exit, visa type/expiry date at the time of those entries/exits and periods when you were in Italy visa-free

Comment: It would be much simpler, and cheaper, to get someone to mail these documents to you from Italy. Is there a reason you can't do that?

Comment: When you arrived in mid-January, did you present the border officers with your student visa, or did you enter without presenting a visa? What were you doing during that time? Were you actually taking classes from the university?

Comment: @Djclayworth, Traveller and Tor-Einar, i’ll answer all your questions together.

Comment: I started uni october 2016-june 2017, all my affairs(permit+grades)  went back to my residence, came back on the 15th of august 2015, during which issues came up and therefore i was unbable to do the whole permit thing and pay uni. I was there until December 12, and i went back to Italy on the 19th of January until the 31st of May. Djclayworth, to answer your question, yes i was attending classes, cause you can do that, but i couldn’t pay or really go back to where i am living at that moment. I came back, and only recently i found out that there is a chance i might not ne let it

Comment: This is a theory though. I migt be let it. HAD i known this, i would have applied for a schengen visa in june, and i wasn’t certain about going back to italy until september 10( out of my hands). I can’t ask my friend to get these documentd, because i need to do it myself, in order to continue in italy ( reapply for a student visa), and no one will give it to a person with a different mail. My guess is that i got let in back in jan and left in may with no fine or border ban( they should have told me if they did, right) is because the permit was in the renewal stage, which i couldn’t do

Comment: So do you guys/girls think that it’s possible my regular 90/180 free travelling kicks when i step foot in italy? And yes, i have a meeting at the embassy at the end of the week to check. If you know anything, it would really mean a lot if you could share the information

Comment: Do not answer in comments! It's hard to figure it out later. Edit the question and put all the relevant information into the question and remove all the information which is not relevant for the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> HAD i known this, i would have applied for a schengen visa in june

A (type C) Schengen visa cannot help you.  The limitation of no more than 90 days in any 180-day period applies to people who hold type C visas just as it does to those (including you, as a US citizen) who can enter the Schengen area without a visa.  If you apply for a Schengen visa for a trip that would exceed the 90/180 limit, the visa is supposed to be refused.

You can be authorized to stay longer than 90 days in a 180-day period by either a residence permit or a (type D) national visa.  The two are essentially equivalent in that regard.  I presume that you entered Italy with a long-stay visa but that "i was unable to do the whole permit thing" means that you never applied for (nor received) a residence permit.

Your question does not state when your long-stay visa expired, but if you remained in Italy more than 90 days after it expired then you were certainly present without authorization.  It's also possible that Italy would regard you as having been present without authorization from the day after the permit's expiration: some Schengen countries maintain that a visa-free stay must be triggered by leaving and re-entering the Schengen area.  I do not know Italy's position on this question.

If you were present in Italy without authorization, then you are presumably subject to a fine and/or a ban, or perhaps some other punishment, but you are correct that they would normally have imposed this when you left.  That's no guarantee that they won't figure it out at some point in the future.

If you have been outside the Schengen area for more than 90 days, then your 90/180 "account" is sufficiently clear that you can enter for a new visit of up to 90 days.  However, it's still possible that they might have you in some database because of some earlier unauthorized presence.

Comment: You have to do it every year. I was able to do it only first year.

Comment: So you entered Italy as a visitor and then stayed there as a visitor from August-December and January to May?

Comment: i think the permit covered August, but after yes, i guess so.

Comment: You are _guessing_ at your own visa situation...?

Comment: I guess so aka yes

Comment: @George88 the permit had an expiration date. What was it?

Comment: It was September 2017

Comment: @George88 In your question you say you have a meeting at the embassy at the end of the week to discuss your situation. You’re going to need to be a lot more coherent with them than you’ve been on TSE; as a start, ‘yes’ and ‘no’ are better answers and less open to interpretation than ‘I guess so’, and if you haven’t already it would be a good idea to prepare thoroughly for the meeting eg create a written timeline of events for reference.

Comment: Great tip, so helpful